# Can 'Favorites' tagged with "Scid on the Go" be searched for in Scid on PC?

Tags: software, database, scid

In "Scid on the go" I can label games as favorites, but then the search filter on Scid Vs. Pc 4.8 does not show a way to search those favorites in the database. Is "Favorites" - Scid on the Go feature? Or am I missing something in SCID PC interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer - 'Favorites' in "Scid on the Go" show up as a "User" Flag in SCIDvsPC, and can be searched for that way as well.